# Number of ways to arrange 0 marbles?

Tags: permutations

> A game has to be made from marbles of n colors, where n marbles has to be kept one upon another. In how many ways these marbles can be arranged?

Is the answer is $1$ if $n = 0?$

Comment: Th number of ways to arrange 0 marbles is $1$.  Yes.  However I have absolutely no idea what "A game has to be made from marbles of n colors, where n marbles has to be kept one upon another" is supposed to mean.  That sentence does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is one arrangement of no things.  Sometimes it is a special case if you are making a recurrence relation, but often not.